# Page resize scrollbar position fixing issue

Tags: scroll, resize, window

When page resize in chrome page scrolling bar moving here is my page link:

```
enter $( window ).resize(function() {
$("section").scrollTo(screenNames[scrollIndex]);
$( "nav li a" ).removeClass('current');
$( "nav li a:eq("+scrollIndex+")" ).addClass('current');
if($(document).height()<400) {
    $("nav a").css("height","2px");
} else if($(document).height()<500) {
    $("nav a").css("height","4px");
} else if($(document).height()<600) {
    $("nav a").css("height","6px");
} else if($(document).height()<700) {
    $("nav a").css("height","8px");
} else {
    $("nav a").css("height","18px");
}});
```

section{  position: fixed;    height: 100%;   width: 100%;    top: 5.75em;     overflow-y: auto;  overflow-x: hidden;     z-index:1; }

Comment: when i click on left navigation green bar circle. page navigation working fine but page resizing page position will going to top.

Comment: any body please help...?